# Processing files in perl and retrying few times if execution fails

Tags: linux, perl, shell, scripting

I am processing files present in a directory.

I am making REST calls for each file, and if the REST response is successful then I move the file to a *succeeded* directory and if it is a failure then I move it to a *failed* directory.

This is working fine. Curl implementation in Perl is working and the directory structure is in Linux OS.

Now I want to process each file in the *failed* directory and make a REST call. Each file is given three opportunities, and if all three attempts fail then the file is moved to some other directory.

My question is how to implement the part which process the files in the *failed* directory and make up to three attempts for all files. How can I maintain a count of how many times each file has been processed, and when to stop retrying?

I am asking for suggestions or design approach which can be taken here. I want the simplest possible solution.

I have thought about some solutions like,

1. Append the number of attempts in front of the file name like `first`, `second` etc.
2. Try to move files in folder structure like first, second, third depending on where it failed.

Let me know if any experts have better suggestions or ideas.

Comment: Why can't you keep the count in a variable?

Comment: You already have two solutions; what is wrong with those? This question will probably be closed on the basis that it is too broad to be on topic for Stack Overflow. The [Help Centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) says ***To prevent your question from being flagged [and possibly removed](http://stackoverflow.com/helpcenter/deleted-questions), avoid asking subjective questions where … your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers: “I use ______ for ______, what do you use?”***

Comment: if you would have read my question, it clearly says any better design or solution any expert can suggest. So that it can be made more scalable and better in maintain wise. I dont think so this is subjective question